# Deserializar Json string[] para string[]

Tags: c#, json

Possuo o seguinte `JSON`:

```
{"TicketID":["116","114","112","108","107","104","102"]}
```

Quando tento deserializar para `string[]` recebo o erro:

> **Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.**
>
> Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros
>   foi definido para o tipo de 'System.String[]'. Descrição: Ocorreu uma
>   exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web.
>   Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o
>   erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor
>   sem parâmetros foi definido para o tipo de 'System.String[]'.
>
> **Erro de Origem:**
>
> Linha 130:                //return
>   response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString(); Linha
>   131: Linha 132:                String[] TicketID = new
>   JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

Vi outras respostas sobre criar um objeto, porém nenhuma solucionou o problema.

Como extrair um `string[]` desse `JSON`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando a bibliotéca Newtonsoft.Json que é uma das mais usadas.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = "{\"TicketID\":[\"116\",\"114\",\"112\",\"108\",\"107\",\"104\",\"102\"]}";

            var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ticket>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(';', arr.TicketID));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class Ticket
        {
            public string[] TicketID { get; set; }  
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom já dado uma solução com um tipo, mas, eu vou também propor uma resposta, na verdade pode ser feita com um estrutura que já existe que é o [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) ([que representa uma coleção de chaves e valores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)) e também sem instalação de nenhum pacote adicional já que no próprio [framework](/questions/tagged/framework) tem uma implementação para tal o [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) que inclusive está na sua pergunta, ***exemplo***:

```
string json = "{\"TicketID\":[\"116\",\"114\",\"112\",\"108\",\"107\",\"104\",\"102\"]}";

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

Dictionary<string, string[]> o = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(json);

string[] items = o["TicketID"] as string[]; // todos os valores
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)